# Botones activan un id diferente

Tags: javascript

Quise hacer una función en javascript pero no supe como obtener las Tag "a" y que por el href activara un div con un id. No se si me explico?.

Pero es algo así lo que quise hacer pero en una función.

```
<a onMouseOver="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-1').style.display='block';void(0)" onMouseOut="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-1').style.display='none';void(0)"><i></i></a>
<a onMouseOver="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-2').style.display='block';void(0)" onMouseOut="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-2').style.display='none';void(0)"><i></i></a>
<a onMouseOver="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-3').style.display='block';void(0)" onMouseOut="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-3').style.display='none';void(0)"><i></i></a>
<a onMouseOver="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-4').style.display='block';void(0)" onMouseOut="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-4').style.display='none';void(0)"><i></i></a>
<a onMouseOver="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-5').style.display='block';void(0)" onMouseOut="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-5').style.display='none';void(0)"><i></i></a>
<a onMouseOver="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-6').style.display='block';void(0)" onMouseOut="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-6').style.display='none';void(0)"><i></i></a>
<a onMouseOver="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-7').style.display='block';void(0)" onMouseOut="javascript:document.getElementById('Point-7').style.display='none';void(0)"><i></i></a>
```

Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: No es facil de comprender tu pregunta, editala , expresa mejor el resultado que quieres lograr y el error que presentas.

Comment: Reformularé la pregunta y el código

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tu quieres es ejecutar una especie de Hover pero con javascript, lo que puedes hacer es agregar un atributo en la etiqueta para que tenga el id del elemento al que quieres aplicar la propiedad en este caso te deje un ejemplo, donde la etiqueta tiene la propiedad showDiv="div1" que contiene el elemento que quiero hacer target para mostrar y ocultar. Para acceder a el se pasan las funciones en onmouseover y onmouseout displayElement( this ) pasando como parámetro el elemento completo y accedes a las propiedades para obtener el valor y hacer target al elemento document.getElementById y darle las propiedades de ocultar o mostrar.

Espero resuelva tu inquietud

```js
function displayElement(event) {

  let div = event.getAttribute('showDiv');
  document.getElementById(div).style.display = "block";

}

function hideElement(event) {
  let div = event.getAttribute('showDiv');
  document.getElementById(div).style.display = "none";

}
```

```html
<a onmouseover="displayElement( this )" href="#" onmouseout="hideElement( this )" showDiv="div1"> Hover </a>

<div id="div1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;  background: yellowgreen; display: none;">

</div>
```